# Footer coming in the div when I use PHP to retrieve data in the that div

Tags: php, html, css

The `div id = "retrieve"` is the `div` where I am retrieving my data from a database. But then the footer below appears in the `div id ="retrieve"`.

Where am I going wrong?

Retrieval happens properly but it displays footer inside it too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Shreegurudev Datta | Home</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--Import materialize.css-->
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans&amp;subset=devanagari,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--fonts-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Chettan" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Advent+Pro" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
        <style>
            body{
                background:url("bg.jpg");
                background-size: cover;
                font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
            }
            slider{
                    width:100%;
                    height:auto;
                }
            /* Add animation to "page content" */
            .animate-bottom {
                position: relative;
                -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
                -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
                animation-name: animatebottom;
                animation-duration: 1s
            }
            @-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
                from {
                    bottom:-100px;
                    opacity:0
                }
                to {
                    bottom:0px;
                    opacity:1
                }
            }
            @keyframes animatebottom {
                from{
                    bottom:-100px;
                    opacity:0
                }
                to{
                    bottom:0;
                    opacity:1
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Corousel-->
        <div class = "navbar">
            <nav class="orange">
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <a href="index.html" class="brand-logo left"><image src = "dattaguru.jpg" style = "padding-top : 10px; padding-left:10px;"/></a>
                <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons" style = "color:indigo;">menu</i></a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down" >
                    <li class = "active"><a  href="home.html" style = "color:yellow accent-4 ;"><i class="material-icons left">home</i>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="history.html" style = "color:yellow accent-4 ;"><i class="material-icons left">stars</i>History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="festivals.html" style = "color:yellow accent-4 ;"><i class="material-icons left">equalizer</i>Festivals</a></li>
                    <li><a href="seva.html" style = "color:yellow accent-4 ;"><i class="material-icons left">widgets</i>Sevas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gallery.html" style = "color:yellow accent-4 ;"><i class="material-icons left">wallpaper</i>Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="project.html" style = "color:yellow accent-4 ;"><i class="material-icons left">today</i>Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html" style = "color:yellow accent-4 ;"><i class="material-icons left">contacts</i>Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="donate.html" style = "color:yellow accent-4 ;"><i class="material-icons left">payment</i>Donations</a></li>

          </ul>
          <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo" style = "color:white;">
              <img src="logo.png">
            <li><a href="gallery.html" style = "color:indigo ;">Gallery</a></li>
             <li><a href="gallery.html" style = "color:indigo ;">Gallery</a></li>
              <li><a href="gallery.html" style = "color:indigo ;">Gallery</a></li>
               <li><a href="gallery.html" style = "color:indigo ;">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery.html" style = "color:indigo ;">Gallery</a></li>
                 <li><a href="gallery.html" style = "color:indigo ;">Gallery</a></li>
                  <li><a href="gallery.html" style = "color:indigo ;">Gallery</a></li>
                   <li><a href="gallery.html" style = "color:indigo ;">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gallery.html" style = "color:indigo ;">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html" style = "color:indigo ;">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </nav>
                </div>

    <div style="" id="main" class="animate-bottom">
        <div class = "header">
            <h3 style="text-align:center; color: #b91100; font-weight: bolder">|| श्रीगुरूदेव दत्त ||</h3>
            <marquee scrollamount="7" behavior="infinite" hspace="70"><h5 style="text-align:center; color: #b91100; font-weight: bold">|| दिगंबरा दिगंबरा श्रीपाद वल्लभ दिगंबरा ||</h5></marquee>
      </div>

            <div class = "cover">
          <img src="banner.jpg" style="padding-left:250px; width:1100px; height:420px;">
        </div>

        <div class="row">
           <h2 style="text-align:justify; padding-left:60px; color:green;">Shree Gurudev Datta</h2>
             <hr width="90%">
            <h5 style="text-align:justify; padding-left:60px; color:green;">|| Digambara Digambara Shreepad Vallabh Digambara ||</h5>
          <div class="col s9" style="text-align:justify; padding-left:50px;">

           <p style="font-size:20px; color:maroon; padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px; border-radius:10px;"> Shree Saunsthan Dattawadi, Sankhali, The Holy Abode of Shree Dattaguru - the trinity of Lord Brahma, Lord Vishnu and Lord Mahesh - evokes deep devotion in the heart of every devotee residing not only in Goa but other parts of the world as well.
    Situated in beautiful sylvan surroundings, the heavenly and serene ambience pervading within the precincts of the temple catapults visiting devotees to world full of divine bliss.
    The precincs normally referred to as 'Dattawadi', is the pilgrimage centre visited by thousands of devotees and legend has it that their prayers are answered by the Almighty. It is also famous as a centre for miraculous cure for mental troubles. This beautiful structure was established way back in the year 1925 ('shakey' 1804 according to the Hindu almanac).
    The Dattatray temple completed 125th anniversary of it's inception in April 2007 with great pomp and splendour. The centenary celebrations in 1982, too, had witnessed similar grandeur.</p></div>


            <div id = "retrieve" class="col s3" style="text-align:justify; background-color:orange; width:250px; height:300px; margin-top:23px; border-radius:10px;">
            <?php
    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $password="";
    $db="db_name";
    $con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);
    $sql_query="select * from Notifications";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);

        //echo '<h1>News Flash</h1>';
    echo "<center><table cellpadding='5' border='5'>
            <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>News</th>

            </tr></center>
            ";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        echo '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$row['date'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['news'].'</td>

            </tr>
        ';
    }

    ?>
            </div>


      </div>


    <!--this footer comes in the div id ="retrieve"-->
        <div class="footer-copyright" style="padding-left:100px;">
            <p  style="text-align:center; background-color:#004d40; width:auto; height:50px; padding-top:15px;color:#ffffff;">In memory of late Sau Sunanda & late Avadhut Dattatraya Gaitonde</p>

        </div>
         <!--close loader-->

     </div> 


            <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/init.js"></script>
            <script>$(document).ready(function(){
          $('.slider').slider({full_width: true});
    });</script>


        </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: no need `closing the table inside that div` ? you start `<center><table cellpadding='5' border='5'>` and don't close it

Comment: Thanks @OldPadawan it helped me figure out my error

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Urgent. Enormous bounty awarded. Come and collect ASAP! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the 'table' tag on line 126 since I can't find it's counterpart anwhere in the code:

```
[...]
echo "<center><table cellpadding='5' border='5'>
        <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>News</th>

        </tr></center> //<-- there is no </table> before </center>
        ";
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @Hapstyx  I got my mistake! Thanks a ton

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could help